# Flink InvalidTypesException: Type of TypeVariable 'K' in 'class' could not be determined

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Flink 0.10.0 was just released recently. I have some code need migrated from 0.9.1. But got the following error:

org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.InvalidTypesException: Type of TypeVariable 'K' in 'class fi.aalto.dmg.frame.FlinkPairWorkloadOperator' could not be determined. This is most likely a type erasure problem. The type extraction currently supports types with generic variables only in cases where all variables in the return type can be deduced from the input type(s).

Here is the code:

```Java
 public class FlinkPairWorkloadOperator<K,V> implements PairWorkloadOperator<K,V> {

    private DataStream<Tuple2<K, V>> dataStream;

    public FlinkPairWorkloadOperator(DataStream<Tuple2<K, V>> dataStream1) {
        this.dataStream = dataStream1;
    }



    public FlinkGroupedWorkloadOperator<K, V> groupByKey() {
        KeyedStream<Tuple2<K, V>, K> keyedStream = this.dataStream.keyBy(new KeySelector<Tuple2<K, V>, K>() {
            @Override
            public K getKey(Tuple2<K, V> value) throws Exception {
                return value._1();
            }
        });
        return new FlinkGroupedWorkloadOperator<>(keyedStream);
    }
}
```

To understand how the InvalidTypesException occurs, I have another example which throw this exception also and I have no idea about it. In this demo, the program works with scala.Tuple2, but not flink Tuple2.

```Java
public class StreamingWordCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        DataStream<String> counts = env
            .socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
            .flatMap(new Splitter());

        DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> pairs = mapToPair(counts, mapToStringIntegerPair);
        pairs.print();
        env.execute("Socket Stream WordCount");
    }

    public static class Splitter implements FlatMapFunction<String, String> {
        @Override
        public void flatMap(String sentence, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
            for (String word: sentence.split(" ")) {
                out.collect(word);
            }
        }
    }

    public static  <K,V,T> DataStream<Tuple2<K,V>> mapToPair(DataStream<T> dataStream , final MapPairFunction<T, K, V> fun){
        return dataStream.map(new MapFunction<T, Tuple2<K, V>>() {
            @Override
            public Tuple2<K, V> map(T t) throws Exception {
                return fun.mapPair(t);
            }
        });
    }

   public interface MapPairFunction<T, K, V> extends Serializable {
     Tuple2<K,V> mapPair(T t);
  }

  public static MapPairFunction<String, String, Integer> mapToStringIntegerPair = new MapPairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
       public Tuple2<String, Integer> mapPair(String s) {
            return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Could you post the complete code of `FlinkPairWorkloadOperator`?

Comment: reduceByKey and groupByKey function in this file https://github.com/wangyangjun/RealtimeStreamBenchmark/blob/master/StreamBench/flink/src/main/java/fi/aalto/dmg/frame/FlinkPairWorkloadOperator.java.  Currently I use Object instead of K.

Comment: I could reproduce your problem. Will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `scala.Tuple2` instead of `org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2` in combination with Flink's Java API. The `TypeExtractor` of the Java API does not understand Scala tuples. Therefore, it cannot extract the type for the type variable `K`.

If you use `org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2` instead, then the `TypeExtractor` will be able to resolve the type variable.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a way to fix this problem if I use scala.Tuple2? Such as to use ResultTypeQueryable? Because I have a high level API which need to implement in Spark also and it needs scala.Tuple2.

Comment: Hi, I just updated my question. I have a demo it works with scala.Tuple2, but get the same exception with flink Tuple2.

Comment: Why don't you simply use Flink's Scala API? With that you can easily deal with `scala.Tuples`. Even with `ResultTypeQueryable` you won't solve the problem in the Java API because you have to get somewhere the `TypeInformation[K]` which you cannot obtain from a `GenericTypeInfo[scala.Tuple2]`. You would have to explicitly pass a `TypeInformation[K]` into the `FlinkPairWorkloadOperator`.

Comment: For your other observation. Your second program works with `scala.Tuples` because at no point in your program you access the elements. Thus, there is no need to find out the tuple field types. It does not work with `org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2` because for this type Flink tries to find out the tuple field types, namely `K` and `V`. As the exception says "Type of TypeVariable 'K' in ... could not be determined.... The type extraction currently supports types with generic variables only in cases where all variables in the return type can be deduced from the input type(s)"

Comment: `K` and `V` are no input types. They originate from the `MapPairFunction` `fun` which cannot be analyzed by Flink.

Comment: Because it sees a `scala.Tuple` and directly generates a `GenericTypeInfo` for it. This is ok, because at no other point it has to know the tuple field types in your program. When it sees a `org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple`, then it tries to find out the tuple field types, which it cannot do (see the exception message).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95716/discussion-between-yangjun-wang-and-till-rohrmann).